# Share children routing

Tags: angular, routes

In app routing module i want to use same children for routing.

```
{
    path: 'add', data: {breadcrumb: 'Add Product'}, component: ProductFormComponent,
    children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'detail', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'detail', component: ProductDetailComponent},
    {path: 'price', component: ProductPriceComponent},
],
},
{
    path: 'edit', data: {breadcrumb: 'Edit Product'}, component: ProductFormComponent,
    children: [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'detail', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'detail', component: ProductDetailComponent},
    {path: 'price', component: ProductPriceComponent},
],
},
```

As you can see both path Add and Edit have same children. The difference is the routing path and data which is breadcrumb. How to share between children so i don't have to write same children again.

Comment: Just make an external array with your children, like const children = [{},{}, {}] and use that in your route array?

Comment: where to create the external array?

Comment: Doesn't really matter? Just above your route definition in the same file? It depends on how you've setup your routing at the moment. No enough code there to determine.

Comment: Can you show me the best practice

Comment: Ohh i see, i think i know

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent },
  { path: 'second-component', component: SecondComponent },
];

Comment: Is it like this?

Comment: Something like: const children = [{path: 'bla', component: BlaComponent}, {...}. {...}];  const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'first-component', component: FirstComponent, children: children }, { path: 'second-component', component: SecondComponent, children: children }, ];

Comment: I ended up create separated module, and then loadchildren to app module. What about this aproach ?

Comment: That’s something different . You’re now lazy loading..